# How to change a users username without the GUI

Tags: xubuntu, users

I am using Xubuntu 11.10 and trying to change a users username. There doesn't seem to be a way to change this through the GUI in Xubuntu, so I am wondering if there is a way to do it without the GUI. Maybe changing the setting in a config file. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First open a terminal, become root

```
sudo -i
```

Next use the following commands,

change "old" to the old user name, and "new" to the new desired name.

```
usermod -d /home/new -m old

sed -i -e 's_old_new_g' /etc/passwd

sed -i -e 's_old_new_g' /etc/group

sed -i -e 's_old_new_g' /etc/shadow
```

The first command moves your home directory, see [man usermod](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/man8/usermod.8.html)

> -d, --home HOME_DIR
>              The user's new login directory.
>   If the -m option is given, the contents of the current home
>   directory will be moved to the new home directory, which is created
>   if it does not already exist.

The sed command changes the name in `/etc/{passwd,group,shadow}`

The system otherwise identifies users by number, not name, so your file ownership and permissions will be fine

To see your numerical id, run the command

```
id
```

Comment: I'm relatively new to this, but I still can't believe I forgot the usermod command. Thanks.